# Remove attribute from <th> in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, tapestry

I currently work with tapestry.
The table has generated sort buttons that I want to remove.

How can I remove the attribute `"data-grid-column-sort"` from the `th` element?

```
<table class="managementlisttable thead-inverse table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr class="row hidden-md-down" data-inplace-grid-links="true">
            <th class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3 col-xl-3" data-grid-column="first" data-grid-column-sort="sortable" data-grid-property="name">…</th>
            <th class="alignRight col-xs-12 col-lg-3 col-xl-3" data-grid-column-sort="sortable" data-grid-property="maxAmount">…</th>
            <th class="alignRight col-xs-12 col-lg-3 col-xl-3" data-grid-column-sort="sortable" data-grid-property="warnAmount">…</th>
            <th class="alignRight col-xs-12 col-lg-3 col-xl-3" data-grid-column="last" data-grid-column-sort="sortable" data-grid-property="orderAmount">…</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>…</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Removing the attribute might not work. Instead, try to find the option to disable the sort functionality when initializing the table.

Comment: Could you tell us why you want to remove the attribute?

Comment: `$(selector).removeAttr("data-grid-column-sort")`.

Comment: The table I created has texfields to edit values and submit them. This works but when I try to sort the table I get an error (Render queue error in SetupRender[UserList:maxamount]: Component UserList:maxamount must be enclosed by a Form component.). It has something to do with the textfields in the cells because when I remove them the sort function works. So my idea was to remove the sort buttons.

Comment: @Tushar is right it will not work unless you execute the $.removeAttr before the library you are using registers the DOM map.

Comment: Removing the sort function is my plan b. Because the other error seems to be a lot harder to solve I thought this would be a way to bypass the problem. I already removed the pointer events from the <th> and set the cursor to default in my css. Now it's just removing the attribute to remove the sort-buttons.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem. 
There is a way where you can set sortable to false for the column.
This link shows how to disable the sort functions
http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/tables/editablegrid1

Answer (score 0):

Another option, since you're using Tapestry, is to change the output after Tapestry renders it to a DOM, using DOM manipulation - see https://tapestry.apache.org/dom.html

Comment: This answer would be much better with an example